# Using ng-click in ng-repeat with $index

Tags: html, angularjs, indexing, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-click

I'm trying to use ng-click on a div with ng-repeat for element using $index as shown below :

HTML:

```
<div class="elementContainer" ng-repeat="element in elements" ng-click="elementUrl($index)">
    <h2>{{ element.name }}</h2>
    <p><strong>{{ element.description }}</strong></p>
</div>
```

JS file:

```
var app = angular.module('portfolioapp', []);

app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.elements = [
                        {
                            "name": "1",
                            "description": "abcd"
                        },
                        {
                            "name":"2",
                            "description": "lmno"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "3",
                            "description": "xyz"
                        }
                    ]

    $scope.elementUrl = function(index) {
        if (index == 0) {
            $window.location.href = 'first path';
        }
        else if (index == 3) {
            $window.location.href = 'second path';
        }
        };

    }]);
```

When i click the div (.elementContainer), the webpage is not redirected to the given path (local path).
Where did i do wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Using the dev tools, do you see the function (elementUrl) getting fired?

Comment: you forget inject `$window`, also you can just use `window` instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for using `$window` in your controller you should inject it

```
app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', '$window', function($scope,$window) {
```

or another way: use `window`, **note:** without `$` sign, instead of `$window`